# How to reformat Windows 7 and install Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, installation

Ubuntu, how can I install you and remove my Windows 7 in my PC? My hard drives has been partitioned into Drive C and D. I want to format Drive C and install Ubuntu in it without touching my Drive D. Because that's where my files are. Thanks ^^ Also I don't have any backup devices, so I need to install Ubuntu without any backup. Thank you ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well , here you don't need any special actions.

Just make a Live CD/USB and boot into Ubuntu Live session as usual.While you reached to partition step choose the option as Something else. I mean 2nd choice in the image shown.

After selecting that select continue and then it will take you into partition step. There select your Windows partition ( C in your case) and then click at `-` symbol to delete. that will delete your partition. Now again select that free space and click at `+` to add the partition.

Choose the mount point as `/` and format as `ext4` and select ok. Now go forward for the installation process.

[image]